# Error: Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm aware that a duplicate question exists to this one, but that didn't prove of any help to me. Here's my index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.formSet = this.formSet.bind(this);
    this.state = { editing: false, ename: "Edit", sname: "Save" };
  }

  formNormal() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{this.state.ename}</h4>
        <p>Hello there!</p>
        <button onClick={!this.formSet}>{this.props.etext}</button>
      </div>
    );

  }

  formEdit() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{this.state.sname}</h4>
        <input type="textarea" defaultValue="Hello there!" />
        <button onClick={this.formNormal}>{this.props.stext}</button>
      </div>
    );

  }

  formSet() {

    return (this.setState({ editing: true }));

  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.editing) {
      return (this.formEdit);
    }

    else {
      return (this.formNormal);
    }

  }

}

render(<App etext="Edit" stext="Save" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and here's the error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
in App
```

I am kind of new to React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of mistakes:
Switch 
   `return (this.formEdit)`
to 
    `return (this.formEdit())`
and `return (this.formEdit);` to `return (this.formEdit());`.

`this.formEdit` is a function, what you want to render in page is what the function returns i.e. by executing `this.formEdit` function by `this.formEdit()`. You cannot render a function, but can render what a function returns i.e. a valid JSX.

Bindings are not used correctly. So i just added the whole example which will work. Have a look.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.formSet = this.formSet.bind(this);
    this.formNormal = this.formNormal.bind(this);
    this.formEdit = this.formEdit.bind(this);
    this.state = { editing: false, evalue: 'Hello There!', ename: this.props.eText, sname: this.props.sname };
  }

  formNormal() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{this.state.ename}</h4>
        <p>{this.state.evalue}</p>
        <button onClick={this.formSet}>{this.props.etext}</button>
      </div>
    );

  }
  
  handleChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({
     evalue: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  formEdit() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{this.state.sname}</h4>
        <input type="textarea" value={this.state.evalue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <button onClick={this.formSet}>{this.props.stext}</button>
      </div>
    );

  }

  formSet() {
    this.setState({ editing: !this.state.editing });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.editing) {
      return (this.formEdit());
    }
    else {
      return (this.formNormal());
    }
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App etext="Edit" stext="Save" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for going through all that trouble! Really appreciate it. But hey, just 2 more doubts that I had; when exactly do we use bind for a function and can you please suggest a good and resourceful place to master ReactJS? Thanks again.

Comment: In short, `handleChange` is defined using arrow function, which will keep the scope of its parent, so no need to bind. `formEdit` is defined without arrow function which looses scope of its parent, thus you need to explicitly bind. I would suggest (https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), its your best bet.